# single algorithm to convert octal to other number systems

Tags: octal

I have come across a pretty neat algorithm to convert a decimal number to other number systems. program asks for two inputs: number to convert and the base. the output is the number in the base required.
I am wondering if there is possible a single algorithm to convert an octal number to the base of choice?

Comment: Yes. Of course there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Any number in any base can be written in any other base. For example, it is pretty easy to convert base 8 to base 2, just go one by one from the back and write each number in base 2 using length 3 (this works because 8 = 2^3), e.g.

```
              0o1234 
    1 > 001
    2 >    010
    3 >       011
    4 >          100
      0b001010011100
```

I bet the same algorithm you use to convert from base 10 to other bases can be easily modified to base 8.